# Pair arbitrary XML open/close tags in Awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to extract block comments that look like this:

```
<tag_1:sub_tag>
This is 1 comment.
</tag_1:sub_tag>
```

or

```
<any_tag>
This is yet another comment.
</any_tag>
```

via

```
 find . -type f -exec awk '/<variable>/,/<\/variable>/{print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0}' {} \;
```

but I am not sure how to make $variable accept anything like using a wild-card `*`. Is there a way?

This has to be done recursively on the sub-folders.

Comment: Don't use `awk` use something that can parse your content.

Comment: Can you show a working example?

Answer (score 1):

Never use range expressions as they make trivial jobs just the tinniest bit briefer but then need a complete rewrite and/or duplicate conditions when the problem gets even the slightest bit more interesting. Always use a flag instead, e.g. `awk '/start/{f=1} f; /end/{f=0}'`.

In this case, assuming your input files are as simple and well-formatted as the samples you provided and so you don't need an XML parser:

```
awk -v OFS=':' '
    match($0,/^<[^\/>]+>$/) {
        f = 1
        end = "</"substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
    }
    f {print FILENAME, FNR, $0}
    $0 == end { f = 0 }
' file
file:1:<tag_1>
file:2:This is 1 comment.
file:3:</tag_1>
file:7:<any_tag>
file:8:This is yet another comment.
file:9:</any_tag>
```

Just stick it in your `find` command and feel free to cram it all onto one line if you find that useful.

If you want to change whether or not either or both of the delimiting tag lines appear just change where the flag `f` is set/cleared, e.g.:

```
awk -v OFS=':' '
    $0 == end { f = 0 }
    f {print FILENAME, FNR, $0}
    match($0,/^<[^\/>]+>$/) {
        f = 1
        end = "</"substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
    }
' file
file:2:This is 1 comment.
file:8:This is yet another comment.
```

Since you seem confused about how to run it:

```
$ cat file
<tag_1:sub_tag>
This is 1 comment.
</tag_1:sub_tag>

or

<any_tag>
This is yet another comment.
</any_tag>
```

.

```
$ awk -v OFS=':' '
    $0 == end { f = 0 }
    f {print FILENAME, FNR, $0}
    match($0,/^<[^\/>]+>$/) {
        f = 1
        end = "</"substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
    }
' file
file:2:This is 1 comment.
file:8:This is yet another comment.
```

`$` is my prompt. Questions?

I'm still not sure why you're having problems but does this help:

```
$ ls
file

$ cat file
<tag_1:sub_tag>
This is 1 comment.
</tag_1:sub_tag>

or

<any_tag>
This is yet another comment.
</any_tag>
```

.

```
$ find . -type f -exec awk -v OFS=':' '
    $0 == end { f = 0 }
    f {print FILENAME, FNR, $0}
    match($0,/^<[^\/>]+>$/) {
        f = 1
        end = "</"substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
    }
' {} \;
./file:2:This is 1 comment.
./file:8:This is yet another comment.
```

.

```
$ find . -type f -exec awk -v OFS=':' '$0 == end { f = 0 } f {print FILENAME, FNR, $0} match($0,/^<[^\/>]+>$/) { f = 1; end = "</"substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1) }' {} \;
./file:2:This is 1 comment.
./file:8:This is yet another comment.
```

.

```
$ find . -type f -exec awk -v OFS=':' ' match($0,/^<[^\/>]+>$/) { f = 1; end = "</"substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1) } f {print FILENAME, FNR, $0} $0 == end { f = 0 } ' {} \;
./file:1:<tag_1:sub_tag>
./file:2:This is 1 comment.
./file:3:</tag_1:sub_tag>
./file:7:<any_tag>
./file:8:This is yet another comment.
./file:9:</any_tag>
```

Comment: Is this just for 1 file? How do I do it recursively?
How do I use this on a command line? It's not responding.

Comment: It;s an awk script. You can run it on stdin or a file. You can run it on one file or many. The UNIX tool to recursively find files is `find` so if you want to run the awk script on the files found by find then either use finds `-exec` or pipe it's output to xargs or to a shell loop. You run it on the command line precisely as I show it being run on the command line I dont know what you might be doing other than what I show to get the effect that `it's not responding` but I've edited the bottom of my answer to be 100% explicit.

Comment: Is there a way to do command line? Pardon, as usually, I use awk limitedly  on command line.

Does it run recursively and search through subfolders by itself?

Comment: I don;t understand what is confusing you. My answer **IS** awk running on the command line and I already told you (and you know this yourself because it's included in your question) that the way to recursively find files in UNIX is with the command `find`. Just replace the awk command in your question with the awk command I posted and the job is done.

Comment: `$ find . -type f -exec awk -v OFS=':' '    match($0,/^<[^\/>]+>$/) {        f = 1        end = "</"substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)    }    f {print FILENAME, FNR, $0}    $0 == end { f = 0 } ' {} \;`

I got

`syntax error`

Comment: The ONLY output you got was `syntax error`? Nothing else to tell you if the error message was from `shell` or `find` or `awk` and/or what line/char the error occurred on? The only thing that jumps out at me from the code you posted is that you didn't put a semi-colon between `f=1` and `end=...` when you crammed them onto one line. Why not just leave them on separate lines first to see that it works and then work on cramming them into one line later if you feel that's useful? I edited my question again to make it even more explicit.

Comment: I tried the command above, but I didn't get anything.

Here is my dir structure:


      $ tree -f
      .
      ├── ./1
      │   ├── ./1/2
      │   │   └── ./1/2/status_file.txt
      │   ├── ./1/oo
      │   │   ├── ./1/oo/5
      │   │   │   └── ./1/oo/5/status_file.txt
      │   │   └── ./1/oo/status_file.txt
      │   └── ./1/status_file.txt
      └── ./status_file.txt

Comment: You can't put formatted text in a comment. Edit your question. Having said that - the directory structure is completely and utterly irrelevant. `find` WILL find the files and `awk` WILL operate on them as shown. Have you tried the awk command directly on 1 file? Did that work? Have you tried the awk command called from `find` in a directory with 1 file? Did that work? How about a directory with one subdirectory under which is one file? Did that work? Dont just throw up your hands and say `it didn't work` - debug the problem and tell us what you saw if you want help understanding the results.

Comment: I did not get any output.
I have also tried to change the format 1 way or the other.
and I also did tried directly on 1 single file, there is no output.

It finds nothing.

Comment: Look, I've shown you the file I am using for input (copied from your question), the awk script, the script running on the file in question, the output from running the script on the file, and the script being executed on the file when called from find. You continue to just say `I did not get any output`. UNIX/find/awk are not magic. There is no incantation or dance I am performing before running the script to make it work. YOU ARE DOING SOMETHING DIFFERENT FROM WHAT I'M SHOWING YOU and so YOU need to put some small amount of effort into debugging it. Add some prints for example.

Comment: I have given you the points nonetheless. 
As I said, I tried, and it did not work. I had also debugged and I don't think you are listening. 

Look, I appreciate your efforts, but I hope it's not just the points you are looking for.

Comment: What more could I do? What is it you think you have told me that I haven't listened to? What debugging have you tried? What were the results? Those are all rhetorical as what I've posted IS 100% THE correct answer but I'm giving up spoon-feeding you and trying to guess what you might be doing to try to help you figure out how you are copy/pasting or executing it wrong and I couldn't care less about the points.

Comment: Thank you, @Ed Morton. I am just a learning teen. I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

```
awk '/<tag_1>/,/<\/tag_1>/' file
```

if you want to pass the tag name as a variable, you can change it to

```
 awk -v tag="tag_1" '$0~"<"tag">",$0~"</"tag">"' file
```

This will print value between any open and closed tags

```
awk '/<[^/>].*>/{s=1;next} /<\/[^>].*>/{s=0} s' file
```

however, not checking whether they match or not.

I'm sure it can be simplified further but this will ensure the open and close tags match (still can't handle nested tags)

```
$ awk '/<[^/>].*>/{sub("<","</");t=$0;delete a;c=0;s=1;next}
             t==$0{for(i=1;i<=c;i++)print a[i];delete a;c=s=0;t=""} 
                 s{a[++c]=$0}' file
```

buffers the lines after an open tag until a matching close tag is found and then prints the buffered lines, resets etc.

Comment: I tried 

find . -type f -exec awk '$0~"<"tag">",$0~"</"tag">" {print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0}' {} \;

It's still printing all over the place.

I am not familiar with awk. How can I make it work?

Comment: make sure your `find` finds the files, then if you don't know the `-exec` syntax, simply pipe to xargs.  i.e.  `find . ... | xargs awk -v ...`.  Of course without the filename at the end.

Comment: I tried 

find . -type f -exec awk -v tag=".*" '$0~"<"tag">",$0~"</"tag">" {print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0}' {} \;

and 

find . -type f -exec awk -v tag="*" '$0~"<"tag">",$0~"</"tag">" {print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0}' {} \;

but none of them are working.

Comment: You can't put `*` in the tag variable, it's expecting the value.

Comment: How can I make it agnostic? ie. anything between "<...>" and "</...>"

Comment: I tried 1 which you mentioned `find . -type f -exec  awk '/<[^/>].*>/{s=1;next} /<\/[^>].*>/{s=0} s {print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0}' {} \;`

which prints everything irrelevant as well.

Comment: Please forget about the find part until the script is running correct for one file, post your sample file input and awk output.  Also please post the awk version you're using.

Comment: I use
`     find . -type f -exec awk '/<variable>/,/<\/variable>/{print FILENAME ":" FNR ":" $0}' {} \;

I hard coded `variable`, but now, I want it to accept everything.

Comment: sample file 

`<variable>
    Here are some comments.
</variable>
`
It extracts it correctly recursively in all sub-directories. Now, I want it to ignore hard coded `variable`, and take any tags.

Comment: Please post the counter example you mentioned in few comments above as "...which prints everything irrelevant..."  I want to see why the script is failing if the input file is in the format posted.

Comment: As commented above, I tried many of them which prints irrelevantly.

Comment: @UrsaMajor without a test case it's impossible to say what went wrong!

Comment: Weird that you got a downvote on this. It's a bit hard to read given all the single-char variables (`a,c,s,i,t`?) and lack of white space but that final script WILL produce the desired output from the posted sample input and you've tried hard to get the OP to tell you in what way it's not working for him so you can help him figure out what the problem is (it's either that his input isn't formatted as shown, or he mistyped your script instead of copy/pasting it, or he's using a non-POSIX awk). I'll upvote to counterbalance.